# SCP command giving some path error

Tags: paths, scp

I want to copy an ISO image from my file server to my xen server using scp. I gave the below command in my xen server console but it gaves me error, dont know whats going wrong.

**Console on XEN server where I want to copy:**

```
[root@xenserver ISOz]# scp user@192.168.1.155:/home/user/ISOz/12.04\ LTS /Server/12.04\ 64\ LTS.iso .

user@192.168.1.155's password: 

scp: /home/user/ISOz/12.04: No such file or directory

scp: LTS: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat `/Server/12.04 64 LTS.iso': No such file or directory
```

**This is the file location on my file server I am trying to copy**:

```
user@server:~/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server$ ls

12.04 64 LTS.iso  list  list~  ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso

user@server:~/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server$
user@server:~/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server$ pwd
/home/user/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server
```

can anyone please correct my scp command

Comment: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
# scp user@192.168.1.155:/home/user/ISOz/12.04\ LTS\ /Server/12.04\ 64\ LTS.iso
```

or

```
# scp "user@192.168.1.155:/home/user/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server/12.04 64 LTS.iso"
```

The reason is a non-escaped space inside your path.

The second problem is because you specified *source* file (file1) but did not specify the *target* file. Probably, you have to type something like this:

```
# scp "user@192.168.1.155:/home/user/ISOz/12.04 LTS /Server/12.04 64 LTS.iso" "user@192.168.X.Y:/path/to/12.04 64 LTS.iso"
```

Comment: Now its giving me this error::: usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: with both these commands

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, the problem may be with the spaces in the path filename that you might have missed some where. So for the ease, follow the below steps.

Try Following steps :

1. Copy the iso file to the `/home/user/` and
2. Rename the iso file to a simple file name with out spaces like "ubuntu.iso "
3. If you have done the above steps, do the following:

   ```
   rsync -avr --progress user@192.168.1.155:/home/user/ubuntu.iso .
   ```

Hope this might help you.